# Link to other Scapple files?

Tags: scapple

My notes grow rapidly in size and I would like to save them into different "chunks". For example, I want to take out part of the notes tree and save those to a different file. In the original file, I want to link to the new file.

Is something like that possible in Scapple? I found these two links with (seemingly) the answer I'm looking for, but I can't make sense out of them or get them to work myself:

http://www.literatureandlatte.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=29212
http://www.literatureandlatte.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=23249&start=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me:

1. Double click to create a new note in Scapple.
2. On Mac, press cmd-L to enter a link (in Windows it's Ctrl-Shift-L).
3. Enter the link to your other file: file:///Users/username/MyScappleFile.scap
4. Double-Click to open the note.
5. Double-Click to open the link.

HTH

Comment: Oh, so that's how... now I feel like an idiot. Thank you!

Comment: @noClue not at all, every question is easy when you already know the answer. Happy to help.